# how do i write this as a list<map<string, string> structure in java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

how do i write this as a list structure in java

In this case i want the structure to be like this, Where options is also a key in another

hashmap called styles

```
options[{"value":"0","label":"zero"},{"value":"1","label":"one"},
   {"value":"2","label":"two"}]
```

Here if i want to access options[1].value should give me 1 and options[2].label should give me two.

How can i achieve this with

```
LIst<Map<string><string[]>>?
```

Also Can i pass "options" array as one of the keys in my hash map

```
     protected Map<String, String[]> getValueProperties(int view, Field field) {
 Map<String, String> properties = new   HashMap<String,String[]>();             
        properties.put("options", []);
        return properties
    }
```

I am new to handling data in this format, any pointers  will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can do:

```
    List<Map<String,String>> options = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
```

and populate as :

```
    Map<String, String> option1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    option1.put("value", "0");
    option1.put("level", "zero");
    options.add(option1);
    Map<String, String> option2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    option2.put("value", "1");
    option2.put("level", "one");
    options.add(option2);
    Map<String, String> option3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    option3.put("value", "2");
    option3.put("level", "two");
    options.add(option3);
```

**EDIT:** You can populate the list in a loop as below:

```
   List<Map<String,String>> options = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

   String[] levels = {"zero", "one", "two"};
   for(int indx = 0; indx <levels.length; indx++){
      Map<String, String> option = new HashMap<String, String>();
      option.put("value", String.valueOf(indx));
      option.put("level", levels[indx]);
      options.add(option);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Yogendra, how would I do this if it was for loop where the map option1,, option2 etc is created dynamically based on the number of entries

Comment: @user1433211: Added a sample code to dynamically populate the List with Map Elements. Please check and let me know, if that helps or you need some different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use this data structure:

```
List< Map<String, String> >
```